# How to calculate standard error of the ratio of two complements (e.g., sex ratio)?

Tags: standard-error, ratio

If a dataset tells me the sex of every individual (F or M), I can calculate the percent female (0.55) and the relevant standard error (0.005). I can also calculate the percent male (0.45) and the relevant standard error (0.005). I can also calculate the sex ratio (M / F = 0.45 / 0.55).

**But how do I calculate the standard error of the sex ratio?**

Comment: Did you make up these numbers? Your standard error shouldn't be so large. Come to think of it, for a bernoulli variable the standard error of Males and Females should always be the same since they measure the same thing in different ways.

Comment: @Hugh: Yes, hypothetical numbers. Thanks for catching my typos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard error is the standard deviation of a sample statistic. If you take $n$ samples there is a non-zero probability that the sample proportion of females is $0$. This means there's a non-zero probability that the sex ratio $\frac{M}{F}=\frac{1}{0}$. This is undefined which unfortunately means that the standard error of the sex ratio is also undefined.